# Quasar Spring Boot Deployment

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, quasar

My studygroup and me build a server with the spring boot framework. I build my quasar project and packed the index.html from /dist into the templates folder of the Spring project. All other files from /dist i packed into src\main\resources\static from Spring project. 
Now i want to return my created login page from the quasar project. Unfortunatelly i just get the code of the Index.html in the Console says:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/javascript: "http://localhost:8080/".

Here my Index.html, maybe it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-    scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width" />
    <title>Quasar App</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="statics/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="app.7d472f6ee58ddd9e9299c9b7cfcf0c2b.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="q-app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/manifest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the quasar build files under main/resources/static of your project.

When you run the spring boot app in dev mode, Spring Boot will automatically take your index file.

In production, you just package into a jar file using maven build